# String splitting using ChunksUpto

Tags: c#

I have an string with var length for example "0009000A000B000C" and I want to split it at every 4 charter or every second charter, the result value I want to put-it in a new string.

```
var str1= 0009;
var str2= 000A;
var str3= 000B;
var str4= 000C;
```

I have try this code:

```
var str =  "0009000A000B000C";
var splitgroup2 = ChunksUpto(str , 4);

 static IEnumerable<string> ChunksUpto(string str, int maxChunkSize)
 {
     for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i += maxChunkSize)
        yield return str.Substring(i, Math.Min(maxChunkSize, str.Length - i));
 }
```

but I don't know how to put the returned value in different string 
Whit the new string value I want to do this kind:

```
dataGrid2.Rows.Add(modbusadd_dec, poiterlangrow1_dec, poiterlangrow2_dec, opt_dec, rangemin_dec + "-" + rangemax_dec, Nunit_dec, Nperfix_dec, Dunit_dec, Dprefix_dec, grouptype, splitgroup2);
```

Comment: what you mean by `every 2th `

Comment: What is `ChunksUpTo`?

Comment: every second number, sorry

Comment: What do you expect the result of `ChunksUpto` to be? Heard about arrays or lists?

Comment: the result from `ChunksUpto` i want to be arrays because i want to covert all arrays to `dec` from the `hex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str =  "0009000A000B000C";

var splitgroup2 = ChunksUpto(str , 4);

public string[] ChunksUpTo(string str, int count)
{
   if(count == 0)
      return null;

   List<string> result = new List<string>();
   int chunkCount = str.Length / count;
   for(int i = 0; i < temp; i++)
        result.Add(new string(str.Take(count).ToArray()))

   return result.ToArray();
}
```

I did not test this code, but it should look like this,
you can take this code, enhance it and fix the bugs (if exits)

Answer (score 0):

You can create method for this :

```
static string[] SplitInto(string value, int startIndex, int length)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    for(; startIndex + length < value.Length; startIndex += length)
       result.Add(valuel.Substring(startIndex, length));
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

And use it like :

```
string[] str = SplitInto("0009000A000B000C", 0, 3);
```